# Rails params not passing to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

This is my controller:

```
class RegularController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_student

  def regular_student
    session[:page] = 'regular_student'
  end

  def generate_regular_student
    @regular = RegularStudent.new()
    @regular.codtitulo = params[:academic_title_id]

    render :template => 'regular/_regular_student_output'
  end
end
```

This are the important routes for this issue:

```
get '/regular_student' => 'regular#regular_student'
post '/generate_regular_student' => 'regular#generate_regular_student'
```

This is my `regular_student.html.rb` form:

```
<%= form_for :generate_regular_student, url: "generate_regular_student" do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :id, @student.academic_titles, :academid_title_id, :name, {}, {class: "form-control 
  screen-only"}  %>
  <%= f.submit "Generar constancia", {class: 'btn btn-default'} %>
<% end %>
```

This is my partial `_regular_student_output.html.erb`, in which I want to show the `academic_title_id` which came as a param to `@regular.codtitulo`, to make sure that I´m getting it correctly:

```
<h1>Generated!</h1>
<h2>Title: <%= @regular.codtitulo %></h2>
```

The problem is that the param never reaches the controller. When I push the submit button in the form, the terminal outputs the following:

```
Started POST "/generate_regular_student" for 172.16.2.67 at 2022-04-26 09:00:44 -0300
Processing by RegularController#generate_regular_student as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"QjHc7k7NXlYgL1XlTiy6rYGgSvID+5II+YusNm7n+i3XT6vNwUzLUxmjG6aTEqAQP6zIKNsetAKpg2L3Qip4AA==", "generate_regular_student"=>{"academic_title_id"=>"221"}, "commit"=>"Generar constancia"}
```

So the param is generating correctly, but for some reason never reaches the controller. When I use `@regular.codtitulo` in `_regular_student_output.html.erb` I just get a blank `<h2> </h2>`.

Comment: It reaches the controller -- your code is not reading it properly.  `academic_title_id` is a child of `generate_regular_student`.  need to do something like     @regular.codtitulo = params[:generate_regular_student][:academic_title_id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dbugger commented, the parameter reached the controller. My mistake was when using it. Instead of using:

```
params[:academic_title_id]
```

I should have used:

```
params[:generate_regular_student][:academic_title_id]
```

Credits to dbugger. Thank you very much!